# isolate node on an object in your scene?

Tags: rendering, texturing, node-editor, shaders, compositing-nodes

I've seen people on other softwares isolate their nodes directly on their objects, in the render viewport, to better work on it.

I was wondering, is it possible to do that in blender ?

Comment: You can use the built-in Node Wrangler addon to do that although you do have to activate it from Preferences > Addons first. See this Blender Manual [section](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/node/node_wrangler.html) which explains how to use it.

Comment: Use  CTRL-SHFT - LMB to activate the viewer on the clicked node.

Comment: @JohnEason Thanks !
I'd also add that the downside of it, is to not forget to do CTRL + SHIFT + (selection mouse button)

on your last node to put everything back how it was

Comment: @Chris ctrl+shift+7 doesn't seem to work...

Comment: @Shad I'd not call that a 'downside'. It seemed obvious to me so I didn't mention it but I've been using it for so long that it's an automatic reaction to reset by CTRL-SHFT clicking back on the original node.

Comment: There's a node preview feature coming in 3.0 that will change this workflow, because it will add the ability to see the effect of each node as a thumbnail, along the lines of [this add-on](https://blendermarket.com/products/node-preview?ref=2).  I can't wait.

Comment: @MartyFouts yeah, though I'm aware, I'm really looking something that show on specifically on your object.